# Multi-threading Issue

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

im trying to make a simple example in threading 
this error msg
can anyone help me to solve it ?

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmb1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Dim th1 As Thread
Dim th2 As Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load (ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  th1 = New Thread(AddressOf proc1)
  th2 = New Thread(AddressOf proc2)

  th1.Start()
  th2.Start()

End Sub

Sub proc1()

  Dim iCount As Integer

  For iCount = 1 To 10
    cmb1.Items.Add(iCount)
  Next

End Sub

Sub proc2()

  Dim iCount As Integer

  For iCount = 11 To 20
    cmb2.Items.Add(iCount)
  Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are accessing controls in a thread-safe way. When you run the application it uses a single default thread to create controls and do processing. Your combo box controls are being created with this default thread. When you try to add items to the combo boxes using a new thread, it is violating the rules of thread safety since you must only make changes to the combo boxes from the thread they were created on. To do this you need to look at the value of the InvokeRequired property to check if you need access from a different thread. If an invoke is required (as it is in this case) then you call the Invoke method and pass a delegate object. The delegate is being pointed back to the same subroutine but this time it will run it as the default thread and no more "Cross-thread operation not valid" errors occur. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, here is how you should re-write your code to incorporate the delegate calls:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim th1 As Thread
    Dim th2 As Thread
    ' Create the delegates that are needd to make safe thread calls
    Private Delegate Sub proc1Delegate()
    Private Delegate Sub proc2Delegate()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        th1 = New Thread(AddressOf proc1)
        th2 = New Thread(AddressOf proc2)
        th1.Start()
        th2.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub proc1()
        ' Check if invoke is required
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            ' An invoke is required so we call the delegate and point back to the same subroutine
            Me.Invoke(New proc1Delegate(AddressOf proc1))
        Else
            ' Original code goes only gets run on default thread
            Dim iCount As Integer
            For iCount = 1 To 10
                cmb1.Items.Add(iCount)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub proc2()
        ' Check if invoke is required
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            ' An invoke is required so we call the delegate and point back to the same subroutine
            Me.Invoke(New proc2Delegate(AddressOf proc2))
        Else
            ' Original code goes only gets run on default thread
            Dim iCount As Integer
            For iCount = 11 To 20
                cmb2.Items.Add(iCount)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

use Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls Property

When a thread other than the creating thread of a control tries to access one of that control's methods or properties, it often leads to unpredictable results. A common invalid thread activity is a call on the wrong thread that accesses the control's Handle property.

Set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to true to find and diagnose this thread activity more easily while debugging.

Comment: The original poster has a very simple example and the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls approach would work in this case but it is an extremely bad practice. Essentially you are hiding the problem and this can cause controls to be accessed in a non thread-safe manner if/when the application gets more complex. This can cause intermittent crashes and other issues with the application which are very difficult to debug. The proper solution is to delegate data from worker threads back to the main thread to ensure that data is not being accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: it is work thank you and useful inflammations Joey thanks

Answer (score -1):

Guessing cmb1 is a listbox or something... You cannot manipulate physical objects in a different thread. Only abstract objects such as variables can be edited.

Put the Integers in a list instead, and create a variable for when the thread is finished.

```
Dim IntList As New List(Of Integer)
Dim ThreadDone As Boolean = False
```

Then do the coding in the thread.

```
For iCount = 1 To 10
    IntList.Add(iCount)
Next
ThreadDone = True
```

Use a timer to check when the thread is finished. Alternatively, use a BackgroundWorker instead of `New Thread`. The BackgroundWorker will do the multithreading AND fire the RunWorkerCompleted event when done.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick()
    If ThreadDone = True
        cmb1.AddRange(IntList)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks cmb1 is a combo-box and i want to display the numbers in it "  listing  "

Comment: Listing? How do you mean? This will add them normally to your combobox. :). FYI: If the threads are ONLY those small For loops you wrote, you won't need multithreading for this.

Comment: sorry im not good in English i mean make list1"cmb1" then list2  "cmb2 " filling 2 combo-boxes this is a simple example i prepared to explain it

Comment: May I ask why my question is no longer marked as answer? Is there something that is not working or wrong with it?

Comment: sorry but yes it didn't work also i used listboxes rather than comboboxes and face problem with adding list integer items in combo box

Comment: Ah, you can make it a List(Of String) instead and do `iCount.ToString()` :)